# Every open and closed set is $G_{\delta}$ and $ F_{\sigma}$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I've seen the proofs and I mostly understand them but there is one thing that came up as a part of the proof which ran counter to my intuition. Are countable intersections of open sets not necessarily open? And are countable unions of closed sets not necessarily closed? I've seen those conditions used to conclude proofs before, however, so I was wondering if there are certain conditions under which countable intersections/unions preserve openness/closure?

Comment: $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (0, 1+\frac1{n})=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard Euclidean topology

\begin{equation}
 G= \overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\bigcap}} \left(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n} \right) ,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 F= \overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\bigcup}} \left[-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n} \right] .
\end{equation}

$G=[-1,1]$ is closed but not open, and $G$ equals the countable intersection of open sets. $F=(-1,1)$ is open but not closed, and $F$ equals the countable union of closed sets.

Comment: Are there general criteria for when countable open intersections are open or countable closed unions are closed however? I'm fairly certain I've seen at least one those criteria used in a proof before, although I may be wrong.

Comment: For a general topological space $(X, \tau)$, $X$ and $\emptyset$ are both closed and open sets. Otherwise we would need to know that we are able to discard all but finitely many sets while still preserving set equality.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Topology/Definition_2

Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space, and $S \subset X$ is a subset of $X$. We say that $S$ is open in $(X, \tau)$ if and only if $S \in \tau$. We say that $S$ is closed if and only if $X \setminus S$ is open in $(X, \tau)$.

Comment: I see now, thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, my first comment alludes to having a $G_\delta$ set that happens to equal the empty set or having a $F_\sigma$ set that happens to equal $X$.